# jquery ui constrain draggable element inside smaller container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to drag an `<img>` inside a container that has fixed width and height. 
I already searched on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279558/jquery-ui-draggable-constraint) but it does not work for me.

Here it is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2es9Luq/) of what I'm trying to achieve; there is a container which is the only part of the image I want the user to show, and a draggable image under it. It has to be constrained in the `.container` element depending on the orientation of the image and the container must include always a part of the image, never a blank part, in other words the image's borders must always stay inside the container.

I tried to work with the containment property, but I don't understand how does the **Array** option works ( http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment ).

Comment: Just use the code from the fiddle?

Comment: the container must include always a part of the image, never a blank part

Comment: allright so you want to change the image size to the container width/height when dragged into it?

Comment: No, the image is previously resized, I want only that the container always contains a part of the image.

Comment: i think this is what you want then. http://jsfiddle.net/WBv9r/106/ its alot of code sadly :(

Comment: uhm..why did not you use jquey ui draggable?

Answer (score -1):

```
$("img").draggable({
     containment: "parent" 
   });
```

and remove `.active`

Comment: the parent is smaller than the image.